# Filemaker main overview table records

Tags: search, layout, datatable, filemaker, relationships

I have two tables: `businesses` and `leads`. `businesses` is the parent table; A record in `businesses` may have many `leads`.

My `leads` table holds data like "calls, appointment, etc etc" - all searchable.

I'm trying to create a layout to sort all of my businesses by my lead information, either with a portal filter or list view.

The goal is to help me figure out who I need to call or see today.

Comment: Can you provide more information about the fields in leads, and how you want to filter your records?

Answer (score 0):

Go into Manage Database and make sure you have an actual relationship setup between businesses and leads.

Then make a layout based on the businesses table and add a portal to that layout based on the leads, which will show up in the drop-down because of the relationship.  You'll also see options in the portal properties to sort by whatever column(s) you want.